# Interpreting negation of quantifiers.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let F(x,y,t) mean Person x can fool person y at time t.

Now $ \forall x \exists y \exists t (\neg  F(x,y,t)) $ means ?

I can write it as

$ \neg \exists x \forall y \forall t (F(x,y,t)) $

I am having doubt of how to interpret the negation outside. Does it apply only to x ?

Should the predicate be " There does not exist x who can fool everyone all the time " or " There does not exist x who can fool someone at some time" ?

In first interpretation, I am applying negation to only x (not exists). Is it allowed ?

Comment: ∀x∃y∃t(¬F(x,y,t)) means: "for every person (x) there is someone (y) that he (x) cannot fool sometime".

Comment: It is equivalent to ¬∃x∀y∀t(F(x,y,t)) that reads: "nobody (no x) can fool everyone every time".

Comment: But can you help me with the scope of negation ? Can you tell me which one of the two interpretations which I gave is correct and why?

Comment: Yes, whatever interpretation you gave was my first interpretation but the negation should be applied to all quantifiers right ? Why only to x?

Comment: The negation applies to a statement (a formula) and not to a variable): in the first case the negated formula is F(x,y,t); in the second case is ∃x∀y∀t(F(x,y,t).

Comment: The first one: "There does not exist x who can fool everyone all the time" is the same as my "nobody can fool everyone every time".

Comment: Can you just tell me the scope of negation outside?

Comment: See my comment above: The negation applies to a statement (a formula) and not to a variable: in ¬∃x∀y∀t(F(x,y,t) the scope of the negation is: ∃x∀y∀t(F(x,y,t). The *scope* of the negation sign is **always** the formula following it.

Comment: Then when writing the interpretation, why are you considering only "There **does not** exist x for all y" and not "There does not exist x, there **does not** exist y".

Comment: Because the un-negated formula is "there is..." thus its negation will be "there does **not** exist ...".

Comment: If we have "There is a cat on the table that is eating a fish" its negation will be "there is **not** a cat on the table that is eating a fish" and not  "there is **not** a cat on the table that is **not** eating a fish".

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you tell me how will you interpret $ \neg \forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ as it is without moving negation inside?

Comment: Which textbooks have you looked at Sagar P? Standard presentations of quantificational logic typically have clear explanations of just this sort of thing. Maybe you can tell us what you've read and not understood??

Comment: "It is not true that for every x there is an y such that P(x,y)".

Comment: Thanks Mauro. I appreciate your patience.